# CSS flex box isn't working correctly, how to correctly align form in css, flex box

Tags: html, css

I've tried multiple things to align this form like the picot below.
I've used flex box a few times and regular CSS.
its also hard because I'm not suppose to change the HTML.

How can I correct this and why my approach was incorrect would be helpful
Any help is appreciated

```css
ul.stacked .with.d {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span>Name</span><img mouseover="buttons/help_icon_over.png" alt="Help" class="tooltip" id="tooltip-registrant_name" title="Put your full name and in these boxes. Please do not use nicknames or initials. If this application is for a change of name you will be asked for your previous name in a later section.  And don&#39;t forget to include your title (Mr., Mrs., Miss, Ms.)."
        src="//s3.amazonaws.com/rocky-assets/assets/buttons/help_icon-bbee0add7434a7895a446d9bb29279210486f843afea4d4ae67a54f262979001.png" /></legend>
    <ul class="stacked">
      <li class="width_d registrant-form__name-title__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_name_title">Title</label><span class='required'>*<span class='required--text' style='display:none;'>(Required)</span></span>
        </h3>
        <div>
          <select data-client-validation-required="Required" name="registrant[name_title]" id="registrant_name_title">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
            <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
          </select>
          <select name="registrant[name_suffix]" id="registrant_name_suffix">
            <option value="">(none)</option>
            <option value="Jr.">Jr.</option>
            <option value="Sr.">Sr.</option>
            <option value="I">I</option>
            <option value="II">II</option>
            <option value="III">III</option>
            <option value="IV">IV</option>
            <option value="V">V</option>
            <option value="VI">VI</option>
            <option value="VII">VII</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your picture, you do not have the middle name, so I don't know if this is what you want. But what you can do if I understand you correctly; Make the first, last and middle name `display: inline-block` to make them span on the same row.

```
.registrant-form__first-name__line,
.registrant-form__middle-name__line,
.registrant-form__last-name__line {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
a {
  color: #23B7FB;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald-Bold';
  color: #797979;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-image: none;
}

#header {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 0;
}

fieldset legend span {
  width: 90px;
  height: 55px;
  color: #ff0031;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-family: Oswald-Bold;
  font-weight: bold;
}



#main form ul li.registrant-form__name-title__line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

input#registrant_first_name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul.stacked .with.d {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.registrant-form__first-name__line, .registrant-form__middle-name__line, .registrant-form__last-name__line  {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span>Name</span><img mouseover="buttons/help_icon_over.png" alt="Help" class="tooltip" id="tooltip-registrant_name" title="Put your full name and in these boxes. Please do not use nicknames or initials. If this application is for a change of name you will be asked for your previous name in a later section.  And don&#39;t forget to include your title (Mr., Mrs., Miss, Ms.)."
        src="//s3.amazonaws.com/rocky-assets/assets/buttons/help_icon-bbee0add7434a7895a446d9bb29279210486f843afea4d4ae67a54f262979001.png" /></legend>
    <ul class="stacked">
      <li class="width_d registrant-form__name-title__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_name_title">Title</label><span class='required'>*<span class='required--text' style='display:none;'>(Required)</span></span>
        </h3>
        <div>
          <select data-client-validation-required="Required" name="registrant[name_title]" id="registrant_name_title">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
            <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <span class="error"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="width_b registrant-form__first-name__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_first_name">First Name</label><span class='required'>*<span class='required--text' style='display:none;'>(Required)</span></span>
        </h3>
        <div class=""><input data-client-validation-required="Required" type="text" name="registrant[first_name]" id="registrant_first_name" /></div>
        <span class="error"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="width_c registrant-form__middle-name__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_middle_name">Middle</label></h3>
        <div class=""><input type="text" name="registrant[middle_name]" id="registrant_middle_name" /></div>
        <span class="error"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="width_b registrant-form__last-name__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_last_name">Last Name</label><span class='required'>*<span class='required--text' style='display:none;'>(Required)</span></span>
        </h3>
        <div class=""><input data-client-validation-required="Required" type="text" name="registrant[last_name]" id="registrant_last_name" /></div>
        <span class="error"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="width_d registrant-form__name-suffix__line">
        <h3><label for="registrant_name_suffix">Suffix</label></h3>
        <div>
          <select name="registrant[name_suffix]" id="registrant_name_suffix">
            <option value="">(none)</option>
            <option value="Jr.">Jr.</option>
            <option value="Sr.">Sr.</option>
            <option value="I">I</option>
            <option value="II">II</option>
            <option value="III">III</option>
            <option value="IV">IV</option>
            <option value="V">V</option>
            <option value="VI">VI</option>
            <option value="VII">VII</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```